# Can't boot Debian testing after upgrade

Tags: debian, iwlwifi

I just upgraded Jessie to testing by updating the `sources.list` and running the `apt-get upgrade` a reboot then `apt-get dist-upgrade`. A subsequent reboot revealed that the system won't boot. I receive the error messages of:

```
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-15.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-15.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-11.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-11.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: firmware : direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Firmware has old API version, expected v12 through v15, got v10.
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: New firmware can be obtained from http://www.intellinuxwirelsss.org/.
```

Followed by a reboot and the continuation of this. I booted in recovery mode and scanned through all the log files with `cat [logfile] | grep error` and the aforementioned errors are same ones which come up with the exception of a few minors. 
I also tried booting into the 3.16 kernel as the testing kernel is 4.2.0.1, but the system just stays in a freeze.

Comment: Those messages only show that the wifi driver can't load the right firmware, that shouldn't cause the boot process to hang. Try waiting a long time (15 minutes), perhaps there are some network operations that need to timeout because of the missing network connection, although I would have expected this no have failed pre-upgrade as well.

Comment: @wurtel I waiting for a day and I tried booting up. It worked. I went into tty1, changed to root and performed a update and dist-upgrade. I rebooted and it works. The only problem I have experience is a freeze which I can't isolate as yet. Any ideas?

Comment: I meant wait during the freeze to see if it continues. You now say you can switch to tty1 and login, so when exactly does the freeze occur, is there anything on screen during the freeze (try editing the grub command line to remove the "quiet" if it's there), and for how long does the freeze last? Add that info to the question.

Comment: @wurtel Done. Despite the iwlwifi firmware errors, my wireless works rather well. How do I address that or remove those drivers?

Comment: @CheddieMerai If you solved your problem, please post it as an answer, and accept it - it may prove helpful for other users.

Comment: @MatthewRock done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I booted Debian the next day and waited for a few seconds (20 or 30) and it miraculously booted to GNOME login screen. I tried logging in , but it freezes after receiving the correct password. I did a hard-reboot and went into tty1 and logged into root where I did a `dist-upgrade` and installed bumblebee with the proprietary Linux driver, removing nouveau. I rebooted and the freeze no longer occurs. Therefore, I can consider this problem solved.